# Testing GWT Apps in Development Mode in STS

Tags: java, gwt

When using Run As -> Web Application for a GWT app in STS, a Development Mode view is opened that contains a clickable link that in turn opens a browser and tests the GWT app...

What are the rules behind changing code while the code is running in the Development Mode.  Does the Development Mode reflect these changes?  Do you always have to terminate and restart Development Mode?

Any tips for how to speed up the loading of the link in Development Mode?

I would pose the same questions for Debug As -> Web Application.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer really depends on if you are running with "Debug As" or not. Actually, the whole topic is a little bit more complex (differentiating between server side/client side code, restarting vs refreshing vs reloading, ...), and instead of repeating myself, I will just provide you with a link to my [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6139199/if-basic-sample-gwt-app-takes-30sec-to-load-in-browser-is-that-normal-will-rea/6150736#6150736).

Note: The Google Plugin/GWT SDK behavior isn't specific to STS.

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't have to restart. Just saving the files is sufficient. Another way to develop is to debug as a GWT app and then open the hosting html/jsp page in a browser and add the `&gwt.codesvr=9997` at the end of the URL.