# GWT and Google Eclipse Plugin: is it possible to run the server in a separate JVM?

Tags: gwt, gwt-rpc

I have a GWT project that contains both the GWT UI and the server backend. The server backend contains the [Java GWT Services](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideServerCommunication#DevGuideRemoteProcedureCalls) that are exposed via GWT's RPC to the UI.

Since the project has grown quite a bit, with the backend requiring more and more time to start, I am considering moving the UI to a separate project, with the idea to *run the backend in a separate VM*. The backend is relatively stable, and it is the UI where we spent most time. With the two in separate VMs, we could work on the UI much more efficiently, since we would only reload the UI (in GWT development mode) and leave the backend running.

**My question:** Is it possible to configure the Google Eclipse Plugin in such a way that it runs the UI and backend in separate VMs and I can still use the GWT development mode?

The project uses GWT 2.4 and we will update to 2.5 as soon as it is out. We use Maven as the build system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two things to consider:

1. You don't always have to reload the server - usually it's enough to just reload the browser page [*] For an overview of when to reload/restart, ... please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/6150736/291741
2. You can deploy to an external server. In an Eclipse Run Configuration, go to the Server tab, and uncheck "Run built-in server". This will disable the web server (default port 8888), but will still run the Code Server (default port 9997, see the GWT tab). Then just run your external server (e.g. Tomcat) on port 8888. It should serve the web content, and handle the servlet requests.

If you want to create a really cool fully automated Eclipse-JavaEE + GWT setup, with separate server-side redeploy on any server you like (even with two debugger instances, if you want), see https://stackoverflow.com/a/11700678/291741

[*] I know, there are certain situations, e.g. when changing Gin configuration or Validation annotations, where reloading the web page is unfortunately not enough. But in most cases it just works fine (as long as you run DevMode with "Run As...", not with "Debug As...") If you want to run with a debugger attached, then I'd recommend the external server solution, of course.

Comment: Gin 2.0 apparently solves this issue - I've only been using it for a few days, but haven't encountered it yet.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Chris, for this detailed and clear answer, very much appreciated.